Vertices connect to Mesh

I want to connect these vertices to make a mesh, but I have no idea how to do it efficiently. I tried to do it manually but it cost a lot of time and I was probaby doing it wrong.

In this situation, I would use the f2 add-on and sit there for half an hour or more, or try convex hull, f3, and then search for convex hull.
